# How to attach TFT screen to RasPi?

Tags: screen

I purchased this 3.5" display from Adafruit (https://www.adafruit.com/products/913).

However, I am a complete hardware noob. Am I suppose to solder the 2 wires not attached RCA connectors to the RasPi board? How to connect it to rasppi ?

Any help (and patience) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to just connect the RCA output on the Raspberry Pi (the yellow connector on the board) with one of the yellow RCA connectors on the display. You will need an RCA cable like this one [Adafruit RCA Cable](https://www.adafruit.com/products/863).

As the description says, if one RCA connection doesn't work be sure to try the other.

Comment: I think you'll need to attach the red and black wires that are on your main cable with the RCA connections to a 6V\12V DC power supply. This adapter should help: https://www.adafruit.com/products/368 with this power supply I think https://www.adafruit.com/products/798.

Comment: I'm a little unsure on the power supply portion of this assembly, maybe someone else could chime in and confirm what I've said?

Comment: Looks right to me, but before purchasing I would email Adafruit.